# Selenium Java can't always click the same place

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testing, automation

I am trying to automate with Java. What I need to do is to choose a random product from the product list and then press the "add to favorite" button on the top left of that product. However, whenever I try to run this test, sometimes it adds the product to the favourite, and sometimes instead of pressing the favorite button, it presses on the product and the test results in an error.

The url I'm trying to pick a random product and add to favourite: https://www.turkcell.com.tr/pasaj/cep-telefonu

mycode:

```
//Add 3 random items
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int productOrder = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'm-grid-col-4 product')]")).size();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(productOrder)+1;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        System.out.println(randomNum + "th product selected");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        //int newRandom = randomNum+1;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        WebElement randomFavoriteClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='m-grid-col-4 product'])["+randomNum+"]/a/div[1]/span"));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", randomFavoriteClick);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        randomFavoriteClick.click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
```

I tried changing the Xpaths but nothing changed.

Comment: At which line are you stuck?

Comment: WebElement randomFavoriteClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='m-grid-col-4 product'])["+randomNum+"]/a/div[1]/span")); this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm exactly where I want to click, I added "actions" to the project and moved my cursor over the element before clicking with the MoveToElement function and it works for now.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int productOrder = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'm-grid-col-4 product')]")).size();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(productOrder)+1;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        System.out.println(randomNum + "th product selected");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        //int newRandom = randomNum+1;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        WebElement randomFavoriteClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='m-grid-col-4 product'])["+randomNum+"]/a/div[1]/span"));
        actions.moveToElement(randomFavoriteClick);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", randomFavoriteClick);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        randomFavoriteClick.click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    }
```